# Equilibrium Temperature in insulated rod from BVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

this problem is giving me some trouble.  It is a review problem given to us to study for our Final Exam this week.  I would love some help in understanding how to solve it so that I can study it and solve a similar problem on my final exam:

Q:  Find the equilibrium temperature in a narrow insulated rod described by the boundary value problem:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$, 
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=0$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L,t)=0$, $u(x,0)=a \chi(L-x) $

[a is a given constant]

A:  We know the equilibrium temperature has been reached when $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$, thus we can say that $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$.  Using integration, we can then solve for $u(x)$ as follows:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=a$

$u(x) = ax+b$

Now we can use the initial conditions to solve for a and b.  We know that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=a=0$, thus $a=0$.  This leaves us with $u(x)=b$

Now I do not know how to proceed from here.  I cannot figure out how to solve for b.

I have two equations that may apply to this problem, but I don't know for sure.

$Q = \int_0^L c\rho A udx$

$P=\int_0^L udx$

Where Q is the total energy in the rod, and P is something that I don't know what it is unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated on how to solve from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that from the two *boundary* conditions, we get $v(x)=b$. But how to determine the value of that constant $b$?

If you solve the initial-boundary value problem for $u(x,t)$ (by separation of variables) and take the limit as $t\to\infty$, you will see that every term in the solution vanishes except the leading (constant) term. So you have
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}u(x,t)={1\over 2}a_0 \quad\text{ where }\quad a_0={2\over L}\int_0^L a_\chi(L-x)\,dx=a_\chi L.
$$

Then
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}u(x,t)={1\over 2}a_0={a_\chi L\over 2},$$
and thus the steady state temperature distribution across the rod is
$$v(x)\equiv b={a_\chi L\over 2}.$$

Think about what this says: for a rod insulated at both ends, *the steady-state temperature distribution across the rod is the average (in the calculus sense) of the initial temperature across the rod* because
$$
v(x)=b={1\over 2}a_0=\underbrace{{1\over L}\int_0^L \underbrace{a_\chi(L-x)}_\text{initial temp of rod}\,dx}_\text{average value of a function on an interval}.
$$